# FileUpload Control in Sandbox solution

Tags: sharepoint-online, file-upload

FileUploadControl.HasFile always returns false.

When I tried using HttpFileCollection

HttpFileCollection files = Request.Files;

after adding System.Web Namespace it says 'Request' does not exists in the current context.

Is there any way to use asp.net FileUpload control in sharepoint sandbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is prohibited by the Sandbox user process and the sandboxed object model. Most properties of the ASP.NET objects (such as Page, Request, Response etc) are marshalled from the w3wp.exe process to the user code process into new "sandboxed" copies of these objects. The Request.Files property is on of those objects that is not copied. It's more of a resource issue than a security issue.

Comment: The requirement is to upload files to Document library from FileUpload Control, is there any other way to do this, in sandbox solution.

Comment: You can use a Silverlight app to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

you can't do that because this is a security issue.